# How to make a copy of schema in Amazon RDS (Oracle)?

Tags: database, oracle, amazon-web-services, oracle11g, amazon-rds

For all the developers in a team, i am trying to automate creating a dedicated schema for each one of them from a 'master' schema. How can I achieve this?
At the end all I want is: given 'developer_1' schema name, 'developer_1' will have all the tables, views, sequences from schema 'master' along with the index and constrains. Online search pointed to DataPump. AWS documentation seemed pretty light. I am looking to have this setup such a way that, this can be invoked every week to get latest snapshot from master schema. (blowing up whatever existed for developer_1)

Thanks,

Comment: Do you want all these schemas on the same RDS instance?  Are they to be on the same RDS instance as the master?

Comment: Yes, all these schemas will be on the same RDS instace. infact the master schema will be in the same development RDS instance as well. Basically I am trying to setup a dedicated schema on the fly, for each developer on same RDS instance.

Answer (score 0):

You will likely want to you Oracle's Data Pump utility. With this, you can create a schema dump (export) and then import that dump.  On import, you can use the handy `REMAP_SCHEMA` command-line parameter to change the schema name on import.

The links below should help get you started.

Export: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/dp_export.htm

Import: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/dp_import.htm

Comment: Thanks Mike, but i am not able to get commandline access to Amazon RDS :( so wont be able to run expdp

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something similar and found this (and then you during the google-trawling):

http://learnwithme11g.wordpress.com/2012/06/07/copy-schema-into-same-database-with-impdp/

I think you can get around the CLI access by using something like:
!mkdir /path/to/dir
then invoking:
create directory as TEMP_DIR='/path/to/dir'
in SQL*Plus.
Also, be aware that the syntax is wrong in site above.

Comment: It would be best if you summarized the link in your answer. Then others can still see the content if the link dies.

Comment: Thanks for the info. The way I resolved it was by using Snapshots. I keep one db instance up to date and create snapshot off of it for each developer. This is very costly but for now we followed this approach.